# Angular2 SPA (single page app) load JS files child pages

Tags: angular, ng-view

I am trying to execute some pure javascript functions on load of a Angular2 SPA child page. I can write my code in  `onInit()` function but seeing ES5 javascript functions in typescript file doesn't look good. Are there anyway that i can load a js file when the view loads in  `RouterOutlet`. `jQuery onLoad` doesn't work inside ng2 view as well which makes sense.

Comment: Not sure why would you want to do this. But you use http service to download a script file in onInit and then use `eval` to evaluate the script string value.